# Removing arrow in ui-select box

Tags: css, angularjs, ui-select

In my AngularJS app I want to remove the default arrow from the ui-select box.

```
      <ui-select
        class="ui-select-no-arrow"
        ng-model="$ctrl.workoutHours"
        ng-change="$ctrl.updateHours($ctrl.workoutHours)"
        input-type="number"
        style="width: 3.5em"
        theme="bootstrap"> 
        <ui-select-match>{{ $ctrl.workoutHours }}</ui-select-match>
        <ui-select-choices
          repeat="hour in $ctrl.getHours($select.search) | filter: $select.search">
          {{ hour }}
        </ui-select-choices>
      </ui-select>
```

Based on answers to similar question on Stack Overflow, I have attempted the following:

```
.ui-select-no-arrow {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
}
```

along with updating the class on the ui-select elements.  That has done nothing at all but if I change the  to  and do the following CSS:

```
select {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  -moz-appearance: none;
  text-indent: 1px;
  text-overflow: '';
}
```

that does indeed get rid of the arrow.  At least in Chrome and Firefox, anyway.

What do I need to do to get rid of the arrow in  as opposed to just ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Dead simple :)

```
.caret {
  display: none;
}
```

Comment: @user3143105 Anytime! I would really recomend learning / digging in the developer tools. It's really powerfull and makes you debug journey much easier :)